# How to know which string is selected from an array?

Tags: java, android

I have written an app which shows ads from StartApp.
StartApp does not have the option to create different ad id's so I created two different applications in their panel and wrote a method to pick app id randomly, but the question is, how can I know which app id AD is shown. I wanted to check in logs but can't figure it out.

Here's my AD code:

```
    public static void ShowAutoMethod (Context context) {

        String[] array = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.irID);
        String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];

        StartAppSDK.init(context, randomStr, true);

        final StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(context);

        startAppAd.loadAd(StartAppAd.AdMode.AUTOMATIC, new AdEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
                startAppAd.showAd();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad) {

            }

        });
    }
```

Array:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="irID">
        <!-- First APP ID -->
        <item>000000000</item>
        <!-- Second APP ID -->
        <item>111111111</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I want it to print the selected app id in the log.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There is no `ArrayList` here. An `ArrayList` is a structure which wraps a primitive array, which adds support for dynamic resizing etc. You are just using the regular primitive array.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for letting me know and editing, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: don;t you have that string stored in `randomStr`?

Comment: Sure. It's no big deal, just thought I'd clarify.

Comment: Check my array @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I want the log to show which app ID was selected when ad is shown

Comment: make `String randomStr` final, and use it in `onReceiveAd` method

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko could you please tell me in code? Sorry but I'm new to this so kinda confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with how all that works but just an idea here, could you use a custom `AdEventListener` class that you configure with the selected id.

```
class CustomAdEventListener extends AdEventListener {

    private String id;

    public CustomAdEventListener(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
        // Log your id here
        startAppAd.showAd();
    }
}
```

And then use it here:

```
startAppAd.loadAd(StartAppAd.AdMode.AUTOMATIC, new CustomAdEventListener(randomStr));
```

Comment: Logs are empty, had to use "Implement" since extending it did not work.

Comment: Altered your idea slightly and got it working. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I did not know if AdEventListener was an abstract class or an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Create a log statement with randomStr's value:

```
Log.d("MY_LOG_TAG", "The selected string is " + randomStr);
```

Comment: I did add this but doesn't this show a random string from that array? I want the log to show which app ID was selected when ad is shown.

Comment: Yes, this shows the random string that has been selected from your array and that you initialized your ads with.

Comment: Nope, I wrote another array for testing purposes and passed down the "randomStr" in logs and it showed string from this one but the ad was loaded from the existing array.

Comment: Did you change the selection of randomStr to the test array?

Comment: No, I did not, that's how I figured it isn't working.

Comment: The logs showed a string from the test array even though randomStr is not being initialized with it?

Comment: Yes, correct. It showed the item from the test array while my ad was loaded from the actual array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202528/discussion-between-sammy-t-and-meggan-sam).

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort but I got it working. Check answered response.